# Flask-Session loses Flask-Login session data after refresh

Tags: python, flask, flask-login, flask-socketio, flask-session

I'm currently building a chat app with different rooms using Flask, Flask-Session, Flask-SocketIO and Flask-Login. I save the user's current room in the session so I can display information based on that room. I'm updating this session data from a Flask-SocketIO event and I'm only able to do this by using the Flask-Session module and not the build in session from Flask. So when I log the user in using Flask-Login, the current users's data is saved in this Flask-Session session with the session type "filesystem". When I then refresh the page, the Flask-Login data is not in the session anymore which causes my program to crash because the current user is now an AnonymousUserMixin object, so the user was logged out. So what causes the session to lose the current user's data? Is there a problem with using Flask-Session and Flask-Login together? Or did I simply do something wrong on the configuration?

This is how the session looks before and after the refresh:

Before:

```
<FileSystemSession {'_permanent': True, 'csrf_token': 'cd2428d22717128228ea31b9182ac46766802839', 'current_room': 'Lobby', '_fresh': True, '_user_id': '1', '_id': '4825ca5a26d88cfc91bcb75ef854505f0d4cdc736affaac2fd3211fb6015b34490c6ec47ec7175dee531442ec8d3a1d5f092c4de1349ca0d48fe723aed678c5a', '_flashes': [('success', 'Logged in successfully')]}>
```

After:

```
<FileSystemSession {'_permanent': True, 'csrf_token': 'cd2428d22717128228ea31b9182ac46766802839', 'current_room': 'Lobby'}>
```

As you can see, the data of the session coming from the Flask-Login module is gone which is why it  says that no user is logged in.

Here is my code:

**init.py:**

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_session import Session
from flask_login import LoginManager
from .models import *

app = Flask(__name__)

def create_app():
    app.config["SECRET_KEY"] = "secret!"
    app.config["SESSION_TYPE"] = "filesystem"
    app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = f"sqlite:///{DB_NAME}"

    login_manager = LoginManager()
    login_manager.init_app(app)

    Session(app)

    @login_manager.user_loader
    def load_user(id):
        return User.query.get(int(id))

    db.init_app(app)

    from .application import socketio

    from .views import views
    from .auth import auth

    app.register_blueprint(views, url_prefix="/")
    app.register_blueprint(auth, url_prefix="/")

    return socketio, app
```

**auth.py:**

```
from flask import Blueprint, render_template, flash, url_for, redirect, session, current_app
from flask_login import login_user, logout_user, current_user, login_required
from .wtform_fields import RegistrationForm, LoginForm
from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash, check_password_hash
from .models import *
from app import app

auth = Blueprint("auth", __name__)


@auth.route("/login", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def login():
    login_form = LoginForm()

    if login_form.validate_on_submit():
        username = login_form.username.data
        password = login_form.password.data

        user = User.query.filter_by(username=username).first()

        if user:
            if check_password_hash(user.password, password):
                login_user(user)
                flash("Logged in successfully", category="success")
                session["current_room"] = "Lobby"
                return redirect(url_for("views.chat"))
            else:
                flash("Password is incorrect", category="error")
        else:
            flash(f"No user named {username}", category="error")

    return render_template("login.html", form=login_form, user=current_user)
```

**views.py:**

```
from flask import Blueprint, render_template, flash, redirect, url_for, request, session
from flask_login import current_user, login_required
from .models import *


views = Blueprint("views", __name__)

@views.route("/chat", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def chat():
    return render_template("chat.html", user=current_user, rooms=current_user.rooms, current_room=Room.query.filter_by(room_name=session["current_room"]).first()) 
    #Crashes after refresh because current user is anonymous
```

**application.py**

```
from flask import session
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit, send, join_room, leave_room
from app import app
from flask_login import current_user, logout_user

socketio = SocketIO(app, manage_session=False)

@socketio.on('join')
def on_join(data):
    user = data["username"]
    room = data["room"]
    join_room(room)
    session["current_room"] = room #Where I update the session
    emit("room-manager", {"message": f"{user} has joined the {room} room"}, room=room)
```

Comment: May be session got expired